# Allowing and finding links while removing HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I recently asked a couple of questions on here related to two subjects

1) Stopping HTML that may be posted by a user in a text field to then render as HTMl on a web page

2) Detect links in a string and where they start and end

I am having problems trying to put the two together.

Over all, I have a text box that a user can type into. They are allowed to type in anything they want.

When posted to the server, I want to seek out all links that are in that text and save them to a database table. Then show on the webpage the text they have typed without any HTML except that I put in myself

So if they type `www.google.com`, i will turn it to `<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`

I can do that no problem. However if they type something like `<p style="margin-left:50px">www.google.com</p>` it will find the link, change the link, but the web page will turn the margin bit into actual HTML.

I was recommended to use HTML encoding, however if I do it AFTER I have saved the links into the database, the indices are off (start and length of where the links are in the text).

If I do the HTML encoding BEFORE I save the links, the links may get messed up. If they type in

```
<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
```

It will encode the text and the link my regex expression will find is

```
www.google.com&quot;&gt;www.google.com&lt;/a&gt
```

I either need to improve my regex, or find another way

For reference my regex is

```
@"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you need to display any other html tag the user may type in as-is.  Try replacing the `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

If you do this before you run the regex replace, it should sort out your issue.